# Mostrar todos los registros con el mismo criterio de busqueda

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap, pdo

Quiero que mi consulta muestre los registros que tengan en mismo curp, pero solo me muestra un solo registro y en la db hay tres registros con el mismo curp. Esta es la consulta:

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

/**
 * 
 */
class Datos extends Conexion
{
    
    public static function buscarModel($datosModel,$tabla)
    {
        # code...
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT curp,Nombre,Calle,TipoLicencia,FechaExpedicion,FechaVencimiento,FotoLic,APaterno,AMaterno FROM $tabla WHERE curp = :curpIngreso");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":curpIngreso",$datosModel["curp"],PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $stmt->execute(); 
        return $stmt->fetch();
        
        echo $stm();
    }
    
}
?>
```

y aqui los muestro:

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class busquedaController
{
    
    public function buscarController()
    {
        # code...
        if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
            # code...
            $datosController = array("curp" => $_POST["curpIngreso"]);
            $respuesta = Datos::buscarModel($datosController,"tramites");
            if ($respuesta["curp"] == $_POST["curpIngreso"]) {
                # code...
                $var = $respuesta["curp"];
                echo '

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img width = "245" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$respuesta["FotoLic"].'"/>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">Nombre:</p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["Nombre"].' '.$respuesta["APaterno"].' '.$respuesta["AMaterno"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">Dirección:</p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["Calle"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">CURP:</p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["curp"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">Tipo de licencia:
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["TipoLicencia"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">Fecha expedición:
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["FechaExpedicion"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-dark font-weight-bold d-inline">Fecha Viegencia:
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-dark d-inline">'.$respuesta["FechaVencimiento"].'</p>
                        <br>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <a class="btn bg-transparent btn-edit" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="right" title="editar" href="../modules/capturaUpdate.php?identificador=' . $var . '"><span
                                    class="material-icons">create</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             ';
                }
            else
            {
                echo "La Curp ingresada no es correcta o no existe.";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el método fetchAll() en lugar de fetch.
fetch abre el resultado de la consulta, para ir recorriendolo fila por fila utilizando un while. Puedes verlo en el ejemplo 2 de https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php

El método fetchall trae todo los datos, puedes verlo en el ejemplo 1 de https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php